# Angular2 : 404 response using activatedRoute and switchmap

Tags: rxjs, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services, switchmap

Method for fetching the selected users details inside service is : 'getSelectedUser(name)', which uses an Observable and in the required component we are  calling that service and applying switchMap and then subscribing to it. But somehow it's not getting subscribed it's throwing 404 on console. Kindly guide in getting that response without any error.

Expected Output is :
When we click on particular user, it should redirect to about/username (here: about/Kylie) displaying Kylie's entire detail.

Here is my code:

about.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from "./app.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'about-comp',
    template: `
                <div *ngIf="users">
                    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let user of users">
                        <div class="content" [routerLink]="['/about',user.name]">
                            <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    `,
    styles: [ `
        .content {
            background: #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }

    `]
})

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    private users;

    constructor(private _cService: CommonService,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router:Router) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this._cService.getUsers().subscribe(
            responseUsers => this.users = responseUsers
        )
    }


}
```

about-user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonService } from "./app.service";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
    selector: 'about-user-comp',
    template:  `
                <div *ngIf="selectedUser">
                    {{selectedUser}} is the selected user  <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goBack()"> Go Back </button>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="!selectedUser">jhjkchd</div>
    `
})

export class AboutUserComponent implements OnInit {
    private selectedUser;
    constructor(private _cService: CommonService,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router:Router,
    private _location: Location) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        //Using snapshot
        // let user = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['name'];
        // this.selectedUser = user;

        //Using Observable
        this._activatedRoute.params.switchMap((param:Params) => this._cService.getSelectedUser(param['name']))
            .subscribe(resp => {
                this.selectedUser = resp
                console.log(resp);
            } 
        )
    }

    goBack() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Users } from "./user";


@Injectable()

export class CommonService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    private UserUrl = 'api/Users';

    getUsers() : Observable<Users[]> {
        return this._http.get(this.UserUrl).map(
            respUsers => respUsers.json().data as Users[]
        )
    }

    getSelectedUser(name:string) : Observable<Users> {
        const selUser = `${this.UserUrl}/${name}`;
        return this._http.get(selUser).map(
            response => response.json().data as Users
        )
    }
}
```

in-memory.service.ts

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class MemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        const Users = [
           {"id": 1, "name":"Chris", "gender":"M"},
           {"id": 2, "name":"Kylie", "gender":"F"},
           {"id": 3, "name":"Christina", "gender":"F"},
        ];
        return { Users };
    }
}
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { AboutComponent } from "./about.component";
import { ContactsComponent } from "./contacts.component";
import { AboutUserComponent } from "./about-user.component";

export const appRoutes = [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
    {path: 'about/:name', component: AboutUserComponent}
];

export const AppRouting : ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here are the Screenshots:
[First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhjfg.png) 
[Error screen after clicking on Kylie user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME6wk.png)

Comment: your question is not so clear, can you please edit the detail ?

Comment: Sure @PardeepJain

Comment: you are not showing code where you click on the user

Comment: about.component.ts is the file which allows us to navigate to its particular user @PardeepJain

Comment: if you want to redirect to `user/username` than why you are using `about/username` ? also problem is in your route, angular is not able to find route as of now, try using without `/`

Comment: It was just an example, ideally i want to redirect to about/username: i.e.about/Kylie and get Kylie's details. @PardeepJain

Comment: yes , just give a try using `[routerLink]="['about',user.name]"`

Comment: This thing is done in about.component.ts. Could you please view the error screenshot and guide me on that

Comment: error gone or still there ? according to error screenshot, angular is looking for route path which is not existed
also please have a look here https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: Error is still persisting

Comment: getSelectedUser(name:string) {} this method inside service is not fetching proper response of the selected User. There must be problem with this method